# How do I force a script to override another?

Tags: jquery, json

My site has a few scripts in place.
First script is a csv to json script.
Next is a 'results' script.  This pulls in the info from the json and creates an unordered list of check boxes and also creates a table of these results.  The unordered list allows for filtering of table to display certain results.

It works great, but now I am trying to incorporate Footable (http://themergency.com/footable/) into the table so it is responsive due to the table having many columns.

My script order in the html head is as follows:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/library/04-csvtojson.js"></script>/
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/results.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/footable-0.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('table').footable();
});
</script>
```

With this I assume the js would fire in that order.  But the Footable portion does not.
I believe this may be because of the results.js that creates this table.

Here is pastie to the results.js: http://pastie.org/6197248

Its creates the which elements are filterable, adds in the necessary attributes for Footable and creates the table.

Viewing the page, the everything works again but the Footable portion doesn't seem to work and hide parts of the table i want it to.

Weird part is that when I open up Firebug and change 'table' in the function above to '#data' the id of the table with results it fires the Footable code and thus hides elements.

Is there a way to force this to happen?
Would this need to be placed with the results.js some how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using AJAX which is asynchronous, therefore you are trying to apply `footable` plugin before table is created.

You need to call plugin either within your `renderTable` function, or right after it in `parseResults` function

EDIT: In addition there is a `setTimeout` being called to manage creating table html within `renderTable`. Plugin needs to be initialized within that same `setTimout`

Comment: okay I've added this footable('#data'); to the pareseResults function, no dice.

I am a little new to custom js coding so please be gentle, lol

Comment: that doesn't appear to be correct syntax for calling plugin..`$(selector).footable({ /*options*/})`

Comment: use a browser console to look at errors. First not sure if `rContainer` is defined and if it is valid selector. Also `{'#data'}` is definitely not valid syntax for an object

Comment: sorry, please see the new pastie link my edited comment above

Comment: make sure plugin loads before you run that code. Again, should see error in console currently that `footable is not a function`. Very easy to look in console

Comment: plugin is running before the code, its the 2nd script right after jquery.

Also, no errors are in the console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24640/discussion-between-tad-ward-and-charlietfl)